# How do this question with the voltage divider?

Tags: voltage, power, current

[image: Question]
I have attempted this question and I got the Vo to be 21.3V, I do not know if this is correct. I am looking for a worked example so I can see where I went wrong if my answer is incorrect. For Io I got 0.89A and for  the power I got 307.2W.

Comment: Show your calculations.

Comment: Hint: the voltage across the 30 ohm resistor is 18 volts so you do need to show your working so we can see where you screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nodal voltage analysis method, which makes things really easy here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJbr5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the equation here would be:

\$Vx/(36+44) + Vx/10 + Vx/(40+10+30) + Vx/24 - 8\$ = 0

And if you solve this you get:

$$Vx = 48V$$

Now that you know **Vx**, you can easily calculate the voltage across R6 using the voltage divider formula, and you can easily calculate the the current across R7 (which is **Io**).

Another way to find **Vx** is to calculate all the resistors in parallel and so:

\$Vx = I1 * Rtotal\$

Comment: If you took the hint in the comments directly below the question, you would recognize that the OP needs to show the attempts made to achieve the wrong numbers. Yes, many folk could answer this and lay it out all nice and easy for the OP but that wouldn't really be helping. Better to NOT provide any answers until the OP comes up with the goods. Note that "the current across R7" is not correct; it is "the current *through* R7" that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" way is to convert the network to a single resistor and find Vo.

Start with the R1/R2 and R3/R4/R5 chains. Each totals 80 ohms, so the parallel equivalent should be easy. Now combine that equivalent with the 24 ohms. Combine the new equivalent with 10 ohms.

Apply the new value to 8 amps to get the overall voltage.

Answer (score -1):

First I would compute the total resistance. Do that by computing the sum of the resistances in each vertical path, and then you combine the parallel resistors 1/R = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + 1/R4. Now you have the total resistance. From that you can compute the voltage U = R * I. Then finally you can split up the voltage where you have the multiple resistors in series. But this is easy now, because you already computed the resistance of each of the vertical paths in this schematics, R1, R2 (10 Ohm), R3, and R4 (24 Ohm). Now R3 is split into 3, but you don't even care, because once you know the current passing through R3 you can find hat voltage over the 30 Ohm resistor as U = I(R3) * 30 Ohm.

It's really not that hard.

I use spreadsheets for all calculations so I can trace what's happening.

[image]

I added the white-on-gray numbers to show the order in which I apply the calculations:

1. add the vertical-path total resistance
2. compute the vertical path's total conductance (unit S - Siemens)
3. add the conductance of the vertical paths to get the total conductance (1/6 Siemens)
4. invert the total conductance to get the total resistance (6 Ohm)
5. compute the voltage for 8 A over 6 Ohm, 48 V
6. compute the current through each vertical path
7. compute the voltages over each resistor in the vertical path

And there is your answer for the 30 Ohm resistor: 18 V

UPDATE: I'd appreciate if those downvoters were to actually tell people what they think was so downvotable.